# General matrix decomposition downgrading algorithm for sampling

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling, matrix-decomposition, cholesky-decomposition

I would like to sample from a multivariate Gaussian distribution with covariance matrix $\Sigma - uu^T $, where $u$ is a vector and $\Sigma - uu^T $ is PSD. I have knowledge of a **non**-Cholesky decomposition matrix $L$ of $\Sigma$, such that $LL^T = \Sigma$. Is there an efficient algorithm for computing a decomposition of $\Sigma - uu^T $ using $L$?
I have found a downgrading algorithm for Cholesky decompositions on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Rank-one_downdate), but I am not sure it applies for general decompositions that are not necessarily triangular.
In this case, I only need to sample from the distribution, therefore any solution that does not explicitly compute a downgraded decomposition is also valid.

Comment: Expressing $\Sigma = LL^\prime$ doesn't seem to be saying anything.  The potential value of such a decomposition would pertain to some special structure inherent in $L.$  What can you tell us about that?

Comment: Knowing the decomposition $L$ enables sampling from a Gaussian with covariance $\Sigma$. For example, if I would have liked to preform rank-one **upgrading**, to sample from $\Sigma + uu^T$, I could have used $L$ to sample from a Gaussian with covariance $\Sigma$ and $u$ to sample an uncorrelated sample with covariance $uu^T$, and combine the samples for the desired distribution.

In my case, I would like to avoid computing any other decomposition of $\Sigma$ (such as Cholesky) as it is prohibitively expensive. Therefore, I'm not assuming any special structure for $L$.

Comment: The use of $L$ is clear. My point is that without some special structure for $L,$ the situation looks unpromising, because having $L$ doesn't appear to be any improvement on starting directly with $\Sigma.$

Comment: I agree, that is the essence of the question. Starting directly with $\Sigma$ is problematic in this scenario as computing a decomposition is prohibitively expensive, otherwise I could simply compute the decomposition of $\Sigma +uu^T$ itself. I am hoping that some form of the Cholesky downgrade algorithm may be adapted the change a general $L$ decomposition, even only so it becomes possible to sample.

Comment: The issue is you need some special structure for L; the Cholesky is the canonical example but other structures may be feasible. Both update and downdate algorithms exist for a Cholesky (where here you're adding or removing an observation, rather than a variable), though you can run into issues with accumulation of error so periodically it may be worth recomputing from scratch. It might be worth explaining more about your original problem you were doing this to solve. There may be an alternative strategy to whatever you're trying to do here.